# C# User control smart tag

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a user control that contains various custom controls (GridEX / Janus). The controls are not being developed anymore, and I need to bring the smart tags from these controls into my user control so they show up as smart tags. Is there a way to do this? Most of the tags brings up custom forms to change settings...

[image: Janus control tags]

Comment: Is this winforms, WPF, UWP, Xamarin, ASP, Blazor... (Please tag your post) And are you asking for design time only support for these tags? Have you tried to google this? Obvious options include: https://www.codemag.com/Article/0707081/Adding-Smart-Tags-to-Windows-Forms-Controls

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.designerverb?view=net-5.0

Comment: It is in a winforms project. I can already add smart tags, I just need to know if there is a way of to add a controls smart tags to the user controls smart tags.